# Is there a Vite config that resolves component imports in Github Workflows?

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, github-pages, vite

After triggering this push workflow in Github, the action does not complete. Workflow error output is below.

I expect the build to occur in the gh-pages branch after the working files are pushed to the master branch.

It appears the build is not running because the imports do not exist in location.

This error does not occur when developing locally.

```
name: CI and CD
on: [push]
permissions:
  contents: write
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install and Build  # This example project is built using npm and outputs the result to the 'build' folder. Replace with the commands required to build your project, or remove this step entirely if your site is pre-built.
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run build
          
      - name: Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
        with:
          target_branch: gh-pages
          folder: build
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN:
```

Workflow error output

```
Run npm ci

added 265 packages, and audited 266 packages in 8s

35 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

> uneven-artwork-react-version@0.0.0 build
> vite build --base=/

vite v3.0.8 building for production...
transforming...
✓ 26 modules transformed.
Could not resolve './components/common/Header' from src/App.jsx
error during build:
Error: Could not resolve './components/common/Header' from src/App.jsx
    at error (file:///home/runner/work/uneven-artwork-react-version/uneven-artwork-react-version/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:1858:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleResolveId (file:///home/runner/work/uneven-artwork-react-version/uneven-artwork-react-version/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22333:24)
    at file:///home/runner/work/uneven-artwork-react-version/uneven-artwork-react-version/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:22296:26
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. Being my first attempt with Github Workflows/Actions, I overlooked the incorrect casing of 'common' in the components' path. The bright side is that the GH Workflow is completed as expected.